# ExecException when adding the new support design library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add the new Support Design library to my project:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

But as soon as I try to compile, I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

I've already reached the 65k method limit a few libraries back, so I already added MultiDex support and solver that problem a while ago.

Here are all my dependencies, if it helps:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.helpshift:android-aar:3.8.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kierans:ViewPagerIndicator:138e5f5bd9'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'
compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.6@aar'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.10'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I know there are a lot of them, but I need them all.

Comment: you should **really** think about getting your `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` play services only grab a portion of it, you can see the guide for it at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split there is no way you need the entire google play services

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sorry for the late reply, I honestly completely forgot about this question after I got it to work. Your solution worked. I only grabbed a portion of google play services and my project then successfully compiled. Thank you. You should post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider changing your `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` dependency, and grab only a portion of the Play Services.

You can see the guide for it at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split , that will most likely solve your 65k issue as well.